# azure form recognizer service - issues with docker-compose

Tags: azure, docker-compose, amazon-eks, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I'm trying to run azure form recognizer service (invoice usecase). it works fine on my windows laptop with docker-compose. when i'm trying to run it on EKS or on an ubuntu 20.04 VM (docker compose with same config), i'm getting the following timeout error.

config taken from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/containers/form-recognizer-container-install-run?tabs=invoice

```
azure-cognitive-service-invoice    | Using file-based Object storage.
azure-cognitive-service-invoice    | Hosting environment: Production
azure-cognitive-service-invoice    | Content root path: /app
azure-cognitive-service-invoice    | Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:5050
azure-cognitive-service-invoice    | Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
azure-cognitive-service-layout     | Hosting environment: Production
azure-cognitive-service-layout     | Content root path: /app
azure-cognitive-service-layout     | Now listening on: http://[::]:5008
azure-cognitive-service-layout     | Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
azure-cognitive-service-invoice    | timeout: failed to connect service "0.0.0.0:50151" within 1s
azure-cognitive-service-invoice    | timeout: failed to connect service "0.0.0.0:50151" within 1s
azure-cognitive-service-invoice    | timeout: failed to connect service "0.0.0.0:50151" within 1s
azure-cognitive-service-invoice    | timeout: failed to connect service "0.0.0.0:50151" within 1s
azure-cognitive-service-invoice    | timeout: failed to connect service "0.0.0.0:50151" within 1s
azure-cognitive-service-invoice    | timeout: failed to connect service "0.0.0.0:50151" within 1s
azure-cognitive-service-invoice    | timeout: failed to connect service "0.0.0.0:50151" within 1s
azure-cognitive-service-invoice    | timeout: failed to connect service "0.0.0.0:50151" within 1s
azure-cognitive-service-invoice    | timeout: failed to connect service "0.0.0.0:50151" within 1s
azure-cognitive-service-invoice    | timeout: failed to connect service "0.0.0.0:50151" within 1s
azure-cognitive-service-invoice    | timeout: failed to connect service "0.0.0.0:50151" within 1s
azure-cognitive-service-invoice    | timeout: failed to connect service "0.0.0.0:50151" within 1s
```

Comment: Did you submit an online request, and have it approved.

Comment: yes, we had it approved and have valid subscription details. it was working on local but not on eks